# MySql: need SQL query for sorting and grouping record sets in table by some rules

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting, grouping

In MySql I have table:

```
idPost | idPostParent | postText                              | dateCreated         |
1      | 1            |  This is parent post no1              | 2012-01-01 12:00:00 |
2      | 2            |  This is parent post no2              | 2012-01-02 13:00:00 |
3      | 1            |  This is first reply on idPost:1      | 2012-01-02 13:30:00 | 
4      | 4            |  This is parent post no3              | 2012-01-04 10:00:00 |
5      | 2            |  This is first reply on idPost:2      | 2012-01-04 11:00:00 |
6      | 1            |  This is second reply on idPost:1     | 2012-01-05 15:00:00 |
7      | 2            |  This is second reply on idPost:2     | 2012-01-06 17:00:00 |
```

NOTE:

1. PARENT post is detected if idPost = idPostParent
2. REPLY post is detedted if idPost <> idPostParent and reply is
   related to post writen in idPostParent

I **need SQL query for sorting and grouping record sets** in table by some rules:

1. Posts must be grouped by idPostParent (parent post first then its
   replies)
2. The PARENT post that is latest entered OR have latest entered reply must be on the top.

The resultset should be:

```
idPost | idPostParent | postText                              | dateCreated         |
2      | 2            |  This is parent post no2              | 2012-01-02 13:00:00 |
5      | 2            |  This is first reply on idPost:2      | 2012-01-04 11:00:00 |
7      | 2            |  This is second reply on idPost:2     | 2012-01-06 17:00:00 |
1      | 1            |  This is parent post no1              | 2012-01-01 12:00:00 |
3      | 1            |  This is first reply on idPost:1      | 2012-01-02 13:30:00 |
6      | 1            |  This is second reply on idPost:1     | 2012-01-05 15:00:00 |
4      | 4            |  This is parent post no3              | 2012-01-04 10:00:00 |
```

REASON:
The PARENT post idPost=2 has latest entered reply post so its thread must be on the top of the table.

Thanks to anyone who may contribute to the solution!

Comment: Generally on SO you should post what you have tried.  A request of this type ("here's what I want, do it for me") is inappropriate and likely to get downvoted.

Comment: Thanks for advice! I'll be more careful next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM posts p
LEFT JOIN
 (SELECT idPostParent, MAX(dateCreated) AS time_of_newest
  FROM posts
  GROUP BY idPostParent) p2
 ON p.idPostParent = p2.idPostParent
ORDER BY time_of_newest DESC, idPost=p.idPostParent DESC, dateCreated DESC
```

Explanation:

The sub-query

```
SELECT idPostParent, MAX(dateCreated) AS time_of_newest
  FROM posts
  GROUP BY idPostParent
```

selects the maximum date created per "thread" (`idPostParent`).

This is `LEFT JOIN`d to the main `posts` table, so that every thread has a `time_of_newest` for that thread.

We sort by `time_of_newest` DESCENDING (this puts thread 2 in front of thread 1 in front of thread 4).

Then, we sort by `idPost=idPostParent1 DESC` in order to get parent posts in front of replies (parent posts have a 1 here and replies all have a 0, and since we sort descending parent posts go first).

Finally, we sort by `dateCreated DESC` to get the replies in order.

Comment: Sorting by `idPost=idPostParent1 DESC` and `dateCreated DESC` can be combined in sorting by idPost, as the parent needs to be created before the replies. Additionally you can use an inner join, as the idPostParent is guaranteed to exist - EXPLAIN shows, that the INNER JOIN will use an index on idPostParent, while the LEFT JOIN will not

Comment: Dear Eugen and mathematical.coffee, thanks for your solutions. There are both good for me! Too bad I have to mark only one answer as accepted!

Answer (score 3):

This works with your test data

```
SELECT
posts.*
FROM posts
INNER JOIN 
  (
    SELECT idPostParent, MAX(dateCreated) as dateLastAnswer
    FROM posts
    GROUP by idPostParent
  ) AS pp ON posts.idPostParent=pp.idPostParent
ORDER BY pp.dateLastAnswer DESC, idPost ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
SELECT op.*, (SELECT MAX(ip.dateCreated) FROM posts ip WHERE ip.idPostParent = op.idPostParent) newestParentReply 
FROM posts op ORDER BY newestParentReply DESC, op.dateCreated ASC
```

Haven't tested it. It would perform pretty terribly too, using a subquery that has to be executed for each post.